# Why is lvl 50 dweller at the bottom of the list?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have a level 50 dweller that I was looking for, so I sorted my dwellers list by level but he did not appear at the top. My initial response was 'oh no, he's dead and I didn't spot it in time'. However, it appears as though he was moved to the bottom of the list with the level 1s:

[image: Level 50 dweller milling around the level 1s]

What caused this? How do I get him back to the top of the list?

Comment: Can I ask if your concerned dweller was level 50, when you received him? It might be an issue with ordering the special dwellers, where they have not been levelled, previously.

Comment: Nah, I got him at level 37 or something... He leveled up to 50 from his time in the wastelands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the same issue. It seems to be related to unique characters.

Your Colonel Autumn is one of them right? You get him from one of the lunch boxes, right?

It seems to be a bug. I have three people from lunch boxes. One with lvl 40, one lvl 50 and one lvl 1. The lvl 1 leveled up and is in front of all lvl 1 and behind all lvl 3 and above. As it should be. Lvl 40 was between the lvl 1 people, just like in your case. After leveling up, he gets back to the lvl 40 people.

Due to the fact, that there is a level cap at lvl 50, your lvl 50 character won't be able to level up. This means he will stay there until a bugfix may be released.

Not the answer you desire, but it's your answer. Sorry.

Comment: poop. Yes he was a lunch box dweller. I have another lvl 47 lunch box dweller who currently holds the top-spot. I am concerned that he will join the Colonel when it gets to level 50 as well.

Comment: No I bet he won't. :-) I have a regular level 50 dweller. He is sorted correctly. :-)

Answer (score -2):

They aren't in order of level.

Comment: While I do not think this should be closed due to content, your answer is rather on the short side. And more to the point, it is incorrect. In the screenshot OP posted, we can see a very clear box around "LVL", at the top. This means that *the list has been ordered by level*.